# Process model in early UNIX

Tags: unix, operating-system

I heard recently that the process model in very *early* variants of UNIX was quite a bit different to the `fork/exec` model used nowadays.

How did it differ from the current state?

Comment: I could have sworn this was asked already but apparently not.

Comment: I thought it sounded familiar.  I mentioned some of this in passing in [my answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/7031/7347) to [Why did Unix use slash as the directory separator?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7030/why-did-unix-use-slash-as-the-directory-separator/7031#7031) (citing Ritchie's paper as my source).  IOW, not a dupe.

Answer (score 36):

If you search for the seminal 1979 paper from Dennis Ritchie, entitled [*The Evolution of the Unix Time-Sharing System*](http://www.read.seas.harvard.edu/~kohler/class/aosref/ritchie84evolution.pdf), it covers this (amongst a few other things like incredibly difficult-to-use file-system links, only being able to create directories at boot time, and why the password file has a GECOS field).

First, we'll recap the current model. A *process* is one type of execution unit within UNIX while a *program* is a runnable item that lives *within* a process (when it's running). That distinction is important.

A running process that wants to start a new process will call `fork` and this gives you two nearly identical processes running the same program (at the same point), where only one existed before.

At that point, one of them (usually the child) *may* choose to `exec` a new program to perform some other work - this `exec` basically replaces the program in the current process with a whole *new* program.

Should the original process wish to wait until the child exits, it can call `wait` to do so.

---

The old model was a little similar but it only ever had a limited number of processes, one for each of the terminals hooked up to the machine. These processes were created at boot time and there was therefore no `fork`. A shell ran in each of these processes, interacting with the user on the given terminal.

When the user specified a program to run, the shell would:

1. Create a link to the file in the current directory (this has to do with the "incredibly difficult-to-use file-system links" mentioned earlier).
2. Open the file.
3. Remove the link.
4. Copy a small bootstrap program to the top of memory and jump to it.
5. This bootstrap program would read in the already-open file *over* the current shell code, then jump to the first location of the command (exec).
6. After the command had done its work, it called `exit`. But this isn't the `exit` we know and love nowadays. What *this* `exit` did was simply to reload the shell program into the process in much the same way as the shell had loaded the program in the first place.

At that point, you would be back in the shell, ready to type in another command. As you may imagine, this had no support for pipeslines/filters but, interestingly, had I/O redirection from a very early stage - all the shell had to do was connect the standard handles to specific files rather than the terminal device.

Comment: IIRC, though not in the initial release, pipes were trivial to add; trivial as in one person spending an afternoon coding (or something like that).

Comment: ^^^ Citation needed.  If anyone has a primary source to back up my assertion, kindly post below.

Comment: @Alex, the paper states that: "Some time later, thanks to McIlroy’s persistence, pipes were finally installed in the operating system (a relatively simple job)". Not the bit about it taking an afternoon and presumably we had to wait until we had a proper fork (to get more than one process per terminal), but it *says* it was easy.

Comment: Yea, I saw that mention in the paper.  The bit about it taking an afternoon (or overnight) is I *think* from an oral history interview.

Comment: Found it: "The basic redirectability of input-output made it easy to put pipes in when Doug McIlroy finally persuaded Ken Thompson to do it. In one feverish night Ken wrote and installed the pipe system call, added pipes to the shell, and modified several utilities, such as pr and ov … to be usable as filters. The next day saw an unforgettable orgy of one-liners as everybody joined in the excitement of plumbing." [*A Research UNIX Reader: Annotated Excerpts from the Programmer’s Manual, 1971-1986*, M. Douglas McIlroy, p. 9](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/reader.pdf)

Comment: From what I understand, there was also an intermediate model where `fork` would write the current process state its slot on the swap area, but then update the "active" slot to a new one, so the next time the running task got swapped would create a new slot entry, while leaving the old slot holding the old process state.  When was that replaced with process models that behave as though a duplicate process is created in RAM?

Answer (score 8):

If you're interested in the early history of various features of Unix, you *cannot* go past the article `The Evolution of the Unix Time-Sharing System` by Dennis Ritchie, presented at a 1979 conference in Australia, and subsequently published by AT&T.

It covers a great many things like:

- the absence of paths, and the use of "link gymnastics" required to get around this limitation;
- the subsequent fact that there was no `/` path separator;
- limited processes as discussed below;
- the fact that there was no `mkdir` and why certain commands (such as `chdir`) have to be incorporated into the shell;
- why the restarted shell was responsible for closing a program's file handles *after* exit (and re-opening its own).
- lots of other trivia of interest to uber-geeks.

---

Now on to the specific question: the `fork` system call was not in the *original* (PDP-7) UNIX, though it didn't take that long to appear.

In the *earliest* UNIX, there were a fixed number of processes created at start-up time, one per terminal device that was attached to the machine.

You can discern this from the very early source code for Unix over at [The Unix Heritage Society](http://tuhs.org), specifically [the source code archives](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl) and, in particular, the [first edition](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V1).

Keep in mind this is likely the first edition for the *PDP-11,* which would have had much more functionality than the one described in Dennis Ritchie's paper. The terminal/process start-up code seems to be functionally identical but, if you look closely, it includes the system calls for `fork` and `wait` (hence this answer is more based on the paper than the source code).

This (slightly modified for readability) `init.s` file from that first edition shows how the fixed number of shell processes were created:

```
    mov    $itab, r1        / Put address of table into r1.
1b:
    mov    (r1)+, r0        / Get next entry from itab.
    beq    1f               / Finish loop if table end (0).

    movb   r0, ttyx+8       / Put symbol in ttyx.
    jsr    pc, dfork        / Call to make new init for this ttyx.
    mov    r0, (r1)+        / Save child id in word for '0, '1, etc.
    br     1b               / Go back for next itab entry.

1f:
    ...                     / All terminal processes now set up.

itab:
    '0; ..
    '1; ..
    0
```

There you can see the snippet which creates the processes for *each* of the two connected terminals. Note that these are the days of hard-coded values, no auto detection of terminal quantity was involved.

The zero-terminated table at `itab` is used to create a number of processes and *hopefully* the comments from the code explain how. The crux of the code shown simply processes the table, calling `dfork` to:

- create a process for each terminal; and
- start `getty`, the login program, in that process, connected to the related terminal.

The `getty` program, in turn, eventually started the shell (see below).

---

Once the shell was running in the process space for a specific terminal, the basic idea was that it would accept a command from the user and then the following would happen (simplified a little, but you should get the idea):

- The shell would locate the program file.
- It would then load a small bootstrap program into *high* memory and jump to it, passing enough details for the bootstrap code to *load* the program file.
- The bootstrap code would load the program into *low* memory, overwriting the shell, and then jump to it.

There was no *new* process started at all, this is more akin to the `exec` function rather than `fork`.

When the program was *finished,* it would call `exit` much like modern programs. This `exit` call would perform the same steps as the shell did when it replaced itself with the new program (except it would, of course, replace itself with the shell).

Hence running programs was a continuous "swap between shell and other program, then swap back when done" method although there were ways to load another program directly without returning to the shell first. It's likely that's how the `getty` log-in program started a shell for you once it had accepted and verified your login details.

---

From this two-way `exec` between shell and another program in a single process, it was actually not that big a leap to adding `fork/wait`) as a process *duplicator/reaper* to work in conjunction. The Dennis Ritchie paper cited below states that "the PDP-7’s fork call required precisely 27 lines of assembly code", a truly astonishing achievement.

While many systems combine `fork/exec` into a single call (such as `CreateProcess` in Windows) , it's this "just add what's needed" method which is responsible for the separation of duties between `fork` and `exec` in modern UNIX (it also resulted in a very simple `fork` function).

---

Comment: When was getty introduced?  In the very beginning, I believe init forked login. Getty seems superfluous with a couple of hardwired local teletypes.  Or do I have that wrong?

Comment: After reading the code, it's clearly getty in the 1st ed.  Nevermind.

Comment: @another-dave: yes, it's listed in the `init.s` as well though, interestingly, in `/etc` rather than `/bin`. However, keep in mind that's the code for the initial PDP-11 release, not the earlier PDP-7 one.

Comment: The PDP-7 version of init did 'login' itself and then forked the shell. No inbetweens.